# how to write main activity class in case of two tables in sqlite database in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

i am creating sqlite database consisting two tables. when i run my program it stops unexpectedly. i checked the log cat where shows the message the FATAL EXCEPTION:Main.i think there is some proper method or steps for the 2 different tables.
how can i remove it?
 following iz my main activity.java class

```
 import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

        /**
         * CRUD Operations
         * */
        // Inserting MapInfoclass
        db.open();
        db.addMapInfoclass("irnumg_admin",035,45,62,72);
        db.addMapInfoclass("irnumg_engirng",91,41,85,64);
        db.addMapInfoclass("irnum_puta",22,71,51,63);
        db.addMapInfoclass("irnum_host9",53,75,69,46);



        // Inserting MapInfoclass1

        db.addMapInfoclass1(035,45);
        db.addMapInfoclass1(85,64);
        db.addMapInfoclass1(51,63);
        db.addMapInfoclass1(69,46);


    }
}
```

Comment: also add full logcat result when app is crashing

Comment: is the above main class coding correct???

Comment: it also shows syntax error in create table.i write thiz az                    private static final String TABLE_MAPINFO1  = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE1 + "(" + KEY_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ KEYROUTE_NAME + "TEXT," + KEYS_LATI  + "INTEGER," + KEYS_LONGI + "INTEGER," + KEYE_LATI  + "INTEGER," + KEYE_LONGI + "INTEGER," + ")";

Comment: u are saying as in post getting `FATAL EXCEPTION:Main` means any runtime exception. if u are getting syntax error in create table query then best way is add relevant code and log with question